# How can I style text that precedes a colon character?

Tags: javascript

Is it possible to have the red-outlined text be bold with some JavaScript? There are no specific span classes so I'm not sure how to do it.

[image]

Comment: It is possible. Do you have a more specific question? As it is it's too broad for SO. Please make an effort and show us your code.

Comment: "*There are no specific span classes so I'm not sure how to do it*" - so perhaps add some `<span>` elements with specific classes?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With split you can do this very easily

If I understand correctly, the answer is:

```js
const address = (document.getElementsByTagName('address'))[0];
let resHtml = [];
let lineSplit = [];
let html = address.innerHTML;
let lines = html.split('<br>');
for(let i = 0; i<lines.length; i++) {
  lineSplit = lines[i].split(':');
  resHtml.push('<strong>' + lineSplit[0] + ':</strong>' + lineSplit[1]);
}
address.innerHTML = resHtml.join('<br>');
```

```html
<address>
  abc: test
  <br>
  efg: test
  <br>
  ijk: test
</address>
```